# Moving <td> elements in table

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have an html table

```
|td,td,td|
|td|
```

if I wanted to move the td on the bottom row over to the right of the row. How would I do that?  Also I cant use a colspan of 3.  I need to move the entire cell over.

end result

```
|td,td,td|
|      td|
```

Comment: css`float: right`? or just add two empty cells before your "real" cell.

Comment: the float just moves the text within the cell, and I wanted to make it clean so I didnt have to add 2 cells before it lol.

Comment: float the entire cell, not the cell contents. `<td style="float:right">`

Comment: Why can't you use colspan? Do you not have access to the HTML or does it not render the required result?

Comment: colspan does not move the cell, it expands the cell.

Comment: Yes, but you could right-align the text (or any inline or inline-block elements) inside the cell that has a colspan of 3 - it seems better form to me than floating or positioning cells ... if it's always the last row, you could do `tr:last-child td{text-align: right}`, for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either create placeholders:

```
<tr>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Or use colspan:

```
<tr>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">...</td>
</tr>
```

Or both:

```
<tr>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"></td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: colspan doesnt actually move the entire cell, it just stretches the current one.  And I was wanting to not put placeholders.

Comment: You're going to need to do one of these two options.

Answer (score 4):

Use colspan and place empty cells until you get to your column offset and use CSS to hide them from view. Simple!

In your CSS:

```
td.hidden-cell
{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

In your tables (for example, in a table with 6 columns, where 4 should be hidden in the last row, using one of them for totals

```
<tr colspan="5" class="col-lg-offset-2">
      <td class="hidden-cell"></td>
      <td class="hidden-cell"></td>
      <td class="hidden-cell"></td>
      <td class="hidden-cell"></td>
      <td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
      <td></td>
</tr>
```

Will allow you to get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<table border="1" style="height:300px; width:300px">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: dear seal though i have not understood your question well yet i think this code will give you your required result

Answer (score 0):

So using Malks answer the only way to move the cell over without colspans is to add placeholder cells.  I did not want to add a bunch of cells so I looped them.  Im using ruby so I did something like this

```
<% 9.times do %>
  <td></td>
<% end %>

<td>My cell has been pushed over 9 cells</td>
```